# How to access student class notebook via API?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

We have a requirement that a teacher can write to students' class notebooks from within our app.

I can access the tutor's class notebooks and the students/groups associated with it.

However I've been trying to simply query the student's class notebook but aren't getting any results (the request doesn't fail).  I'm trying:

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/users/{id}/notes/classnotebooks/
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by the API. Please feel free to make this suggestion under OneNote's UserVoice page at https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I thought as much.  However having investigated further it looks as though I could "fudge" something to achieve this:  get "studentSections" of class notebook,  query sections where parent notebook = class notebook and name = studentSection (this gives the section id for each student with their name in the parentSectionGroup).   Is this acceptable in production code?  Any risk to doing it this way?

Comment: So something like this: api/v1.0/me/notes/sections?filter=tolower(name) eq 'class notes' and parentNotebook/id eq 'id'

Comment: On further investigation this isn't a solution as section names are localised.